# Why does \p{Ll} not match small case umlauts?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre

In PHP I use this PCRE-regular expression:

```
\p{Ll}
```

And it matches lower case letters like `a`, `b`, `c`, but not `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `ß`. (it correctly does not match upper case characters, numbers, etc)

See online: https://regexr.com/440eq

Why does it not match those german unicode small caps characters? And how can I make it match them?

See also the official PHP [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.unicode.php) documentation.

Comment: It must be a bug -- `\p{Lu}` matches both lower and  and upper case a umlaut: https://regexr.com/440f0. But it's not reproducible on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9HG2zG/1)

Comment: It matches, you miss the `u` flag. At [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iITbUZ/1), the `u` modifier behavior is default (even if you do not select it in the UI). See https://3v4l.org/qih6M